# Xpath based on another element value

Tags: xpath

I need to use Selenium Java to click on some links based on another element in the same line. I have the following HTML:

[HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnWTV.png)

I need to click on the `span` link (red color) of every line which contains that empty checkbox (green color). I can find all empty checkboxes by using xpath `//img[contains(@src,'completion-auto-n')]`, but I can't find a XPATH to click on these `span` based on the checkbox's values.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post the actual HTML. It is fine to include the image and drawing to supplement the description, but if you want people to help you with XPath, it is much easier for them to copy/paste the HTML and work on a solution. You are more likely to get help if you make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `img` elements, you could use the `ancestor::` axis with a predicate to look up the tree for the first `div`, and then look down the tree with the `//` descendant axis from that `div` for an `span` that is a child of an `a`:

```
//img[contains(@src,'completion-auto-n')]/ancestor::div[1]//a/span
```